# Float64 to Float32

Tags: c++, ros

I am trying to send a ROS std_msgsFloat32 a float64 however, it will not automatically downcast. How can you safely convert a std_msgs::Float64 to a std_msgs::Float32?

Code with downcasting problem:

```
//currentLocation.theta is a Float64, thetaPublish accepts Float32
thetaPublish.publish(currentLocation.theta);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
std_msgs::Float32 theta32;
theta32.data = static_cast<float>(theta.data);
thetaPublish.publish(theta32);
```

You just need to explicitly copy the double `data` to a float.

Comment: Thank you I will test it now! <3

Comment: invalid cast from type ‘std_msgs::Float64’ to type ‘float’
     theta32.data = (float) theta.data

Comment: Hmm, works for me with or without the cast. I'm using Indigo on Linux, if that's a factor. Try `static_cast<float>(theta.data)` just in case there is an odd macro somewhere.

Comment: Thanks I will try when I get back home on my indigo.